# href retrieval with cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have a downloaded html file that looks something like this

```
<html class="theme_">
<head>
<body>
    <div id="ad_1"></div>
    ...
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="top" style="height:11px;color:white;font-size:9px;font-weight:bold;"> </div>
        ...
        <div id="content" style="border-top:none;">
            ...
            <table id="user_list">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="trodd">
                        <td width="10%" valign="center" align="center">
                        <td class="list_art" style="width:160px;">
                        <td class="main_entry">
                            <h4>
                            <h5>
                                <a class="list_album" href="https://rateyourmusic.com/release/single/electra__ita_/feels_good__carrots_and_beets_/" title="[Album833409]">Feels Good (Carrots & Beets)</a>
                                <span class="rel_date">(1982) [Single]</span>
                                </h5>
                            </td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="treven">
```

I need to get to each of the `<tr class="trodd">` and `<tr class="treven">` entries of the table `user_list` and retrieve the href. This is the code I have now and it returns just an empty array. One of the things I can't get a grasp on is whether cheerio is capable of finding each `class="list_album"` like this or you have to make your way down the file's hierarchy with a bunch of `$( )`'s.

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var file = "...path...";
var links = [];

var $ = cheerio.load(file);
$('list_album').each( function () {
    var link = $(this.attr('href'));
    links.push({"link": link});
});

console.log(links);
```

Answer (score 26):

I did this and it worked for me:

Make sure to use `$(value)` instead of `$(this)`

```
$('.list_album').each( (index, value) => {
   var link = $(value).attr('href');
   links.push({"link": link});
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I will answer here.
It seems a typo, the 'dot' on selector and the $ wrapper. Try this.

```
$('.list_album').each( function () {
   var link = $(this).attr('href');
   links.push({"link": link});
});
```

Comment: yes, I've seen some cheerio examples and noticed these same two things as well. It still returns an empty array. I appreciate the input, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
const getHTML = async html => {
    const req =  await axios.get(html)
    const res =  await req.data
    return res
}
const parser = res => {
    let data = []
    const $  = cheerio.load(res)

    $('table tr td').each((i, elem) => {
        data.push($(elem).find('a').attr('href'))
    })
    return data
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have reputation to comment but may help someone.OP did not add dot in given snippet.
instead of `$('list_album')`, you need to use `$('.list_album')`.Here dot operator is class selector.