# Function is unable to get all urls under certain div. Node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

I am developing a basic web scraper for 'play store' and I have written a code to get URLs uder `<div class="ZmHEEd"....> .... </div>` tag. But output is displayed as and empty array. I was following [href retrieval with cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438048/href-retrieval-with-cheerio)

> output: [ ]

```
var express = require('express');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var request = require('request');
    var cheerio = require('cheerio');
    var app     = express();


var file = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=CiMKIQobdG9wc2VsbGluZ19mcmVlX0FQUExJQ0FUSU9OEAcYAw%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljKtW7s&gsr=CiUKIwohCht0b3BzZWxsaW5nX2ZyZWVfQVBQTElDQVRJT04QBxgD:S:ANO1ljL_-aM';
var links = [];
var $ = cheerio.load(file);
$('.ZmHEEd ').each( function () {
   var link = $(this).attr('href');
   links.push({'link': link});
});
console.log(links);
```

> snippet from [Playstore free apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=CiMKIQobdG9wc2VsbGluZ19mcmVlX0FQUExJQ0FUSU9OEAcYAw%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljKtW7s&gsr=CiUKIwohCht0b3BzZWxsaW5nX2ZyZWVfQVBQTElDQVRJT04QBxgD:S:ANO1ljL_-aM)

```html
<div class="vU6FJ p63iDd">
 <a href="/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" class="JC71ub"></a>
 <div class="k6AFYd"><div class="bQVA0c">
  <div class="PODJt"><div class="kCSSQe">
   <div class="b8cIId ReQCgd Q9MA7b" title="WhatsApp Messenger">
    <a href="/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp">
     <div class="WsMG1c nnK0zc">WhatsApp Messenger</div>
   </a>
    <div class="cqtbn"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="b8cIId ReQCgd KoLSrc" title="">
    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=WhatsApp+Inc." class="mnKHRc">
     <div>WhatsApp Inc.</div>
     </a>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is `.ZmHEEd ` an `<a>` tag? There's a space in the end.

Comment: no its <div> element. I have edited my question for clarification

Comment: `div` tags don't have `href` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Because `div` tag doesn't contain href attribute, you can't do so. instead you can use `a` tag or `data-attribute` to achieve it:

**HTML**

```
<div class="ZmHEEd" data-href="you_href"....> .... </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.ZmHEEd ').each( function () {
   var link = $(this).attr('data-href');
   links.push({'link': link});
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I cannot edit html as. ` <div class="ZmHEEd" data-href="you_href"....> .... </div> `  because I am have to crawl from html source of play store. https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=CiMKIQobdG9wc2VsbGluZ19mcmVlX0FQUExJQ0FUSU9OEAcYAw%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljKtW7s&gsr=CiUKIwohCht0b3BzZWxsaW5nX2ZyZWVfQVBQTElDQVRJT04QBxgD:S:ANO1ljL_-aM. How can I get urls of all application using <a>  tag?